# Python file directory issues

Tags: python, directory

I created a python project and placed all the stuffs.i.e. a folder containing images, Csv files,py files etc. in a separate folder name "Final Project". The program was running well.

After evaluation was done, I put that folder inside another folder named "Tasks" to that contained my homework files, Quizzes, and all tasks related to python.
But now when I ran my program again, after few weeks, it gave "no such file or directory" error for images used in my program.
When I again removed the folder "Final Project" from folder "Tasks", and separated it, All goes well again.

Inshort, my program runs well in this directory sequence:
**D:\4th Semester\CP-II\Final Project**
But gives error in this sequence:
**D:\4th Semester\CP-II\Tasks\Final Project**
[image]

Comment: Could you please post the your code for us to take a look?

Comment: A screenshot is added

Comment: Would there be any difference in folder permission between Tasks and CP-II ?

Comment: @Henry Mont Sorry I am unable to understand your question :(